# Understanding this Rewrite rule to achieve the same effect as Apache Multiviews

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This rewrite rule is working fine on a Litespeed server to achieve the same result as Apache's Multiviews

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.+php* 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(.*)$ $1.php/$2 [L]
```

But there are a couple of things that I don't understand;

The first RewriteCond line, from my understanding the `!.+php*` would prevent any string that has "php" somewhere in the middle or possibly at the end to evaluate to true? What's the purpose of this?

On the second RewriteCond line, what is the $1 referencing? Is it the first parenthesis from the RewriteRule line which is below it? I thought that references could only reference things that were defined "previously" not after it?

Also this rule is working fine when I upload to the live server running Litespeed but fails on my local development environment running Apache? I disabled Multiviews in Apache so this rewrite rule should work just like it does on Litespeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first RewriteCond line, from my understanding the !.+php* would prevent any string that has "php" somewhere in the middle or possibly at the end to evaluate to true? What's the purpose of this?

This doesn't look right. the `!` is negation (not), the `.+` is anything that is at least 1 character. The `php*` means a "p", then a "h", then either 0 or more "p"'s. What you probably want is just:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php
```

> On the second RewriteCond line, what is the $1 referencing? Is it the first parenthesis from the RewriteRule line which is below it? I thought that references could only reference things that were defined "previously" not after it?

Yes, it references the `([^/]+)` in the rule. What actually happens when mod rewrite processes a rule is it applies the regex pattern in the `RewriteRule` **first**, then if the pattern matches, it then checks each of the `RewriteCond`'s associated with the rule (it's more efficient this way, since there's no need to check all the conditions if the rule's pattern doesn't even match).

As for why it's not working:

1. Make sure mod rewrite is turned on
2. Make sure you have `AllowOverride All` or at least `AllowOverride FileInfo` set in the server/vhost config for the directory your htaccess file is in (or its parent(s))
3. Make sure your htaccess file is actually where it should be (looks like this wants to be in the *document root*)
4. Make sure your htaccess file is being read at all (put some gibberish in it and see if you get a 500 server error), and if not, check what your `[AccessFilename](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#accessfilename)` directive is set to. It should be set to `.htaccess`
5. Check your error logs